# Running Ubuntu Desktop in LXC/LXD on top of Ubuntu Server

Tags: lxc, lxd

Is it possible to have Ubuntu Desktop running in an LXC/LXD container on top of Ubuntu Server, displaying Ubuntu Desktop's graphical X session on the physical screen that Ubuntu Server outputs to?

Whether it makes sense or not, my idea is to separate the Server "PC" from the Desktop "PC". I intend to set up an Intel NUC machine as a personal web server as well as a HTPC machine connected to my TV.

Comment: Here's another link to check out: https://www.reddit.com/r/LXC/comments/425l3p/tip_if_you_are_using_lxdlxc_to_create_desktop/

What did you end up doing with this?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I ended on installing Ubuntu Desktop (to have the Desktop GUI) and run the server related things alongside it. I might one day reinstall the whole NUC if I figure out how to run the Desktop inside an LXC/LXD container.

Comment: I don't know about connecting the container's console to the host display, but if you're using RealVNC (with system Xorg), ubuntu desktop works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Not definitely true:)That won't work!(/Not definitely true) What would work though, is doing it the other way round: install the Desktop on your machine and then use LXD to run the web server.

Also, if you have a current NUC box, you should have processor virtualization and could run KVM. I'm not familiar with that, but it seems your chances are better with a true VM solution...

Comment: I was starting to fear this would be the answer. Before I accept this answer, how sure are you? Do you have some reference for this?

Comment: No, I don't. And maybe I've been a bit premature? I had a look at the link provided by Davei and also at this: [link](https://www.stgraber.org/2014/02/09/lxc-1-0-gui-in-containers/).The following IS true: I assumed that, when you wrote "server", you mean some basic installation from an Ubuntu server image. In this case neither of these two solutions will work, since they rely on devices which are not present in a server installation, e.g. '/dev/video0'.

Comment: KVM: I just started with that and it seems you're out of luck there too. The guides say that in order to install a GUI-based system on a server, you have to create the VM and then use VNC or virt-viewer from a GUI client to finish the installation.

Comment: I appreciate the time and effort you put into this. The "other way around" solution is what I need to do. Ubuntu Server in a LXD container on top of standard Ubuntu Desktop installation.

Comment: Thank you! Honestly I just happened to play around with virtualization solutions right now. Love LXD for the Linux server-side! KVM is OK, it runs Win10 on top of VMware Player on a Win10 host ;-) But a local console is always tricky. Next stop: Hyper-V!

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible with LXD.

I have my custom LXD Image server. Please do the following:

```
sudo lxc remote add codedream lxdimage.codedream.ml --public 
sudo lxc launch codedream:ubuntu1604-kodhe-xfcedesktop my-desktop -c "security.privileged=true" -c "security.nesting=true"
```

Or if you prefer unity desktop:

```
sudo lxc remote add codedream lxdimage.codedream.ml --public 
sudo lxc launch codedream:ubuntu1604-kodhe-unitydesktop my-desktop -c "security.privileged=true" -c "security.nesting=true"
```

Also now have ukui:

```
sudo lxc remote add codedream lxdimage.codedream.ml --public 
sudo lxc launch codedream:ukui my-desktop -c "security.privileged=true" -c "security.nesting=true"
```

After, install [NoMachine](https://www.nomachine.com/), and connect to lxd container by IP and port 4000. **Username**=kodhe, **Password**=1. To view IP:

```
sudo lxc list my-desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help
https://github.com/ustuehler/lxc-desktop
It seems you can run multiple desktop instances in lxc containers, however I'm not sure why you would want the server part to have a desktop interface

Comment: Think of the Desktop as a service. Just as I isolate my Django site in a Linux container, I'd like to isolate my Desktop session in a container.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes, as mentioned in previous answers. For good how to's, I highly recommend this playlist created by the maintainer of the LXD project Stéphane Graber: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLddduKsl-KEhleT9VTR4hbtlNdtMr6cFd , See video #23 (and enjoy the full playlist).